# libavcodec on media entirely in memory

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I'm dealing with small micro videos that exist entirely in memory (as a string). So far, I haven't been able to get avcodec to properly decode h264 in this way.

I tried a custom AVIOContext that operates on containerized media:

```
struct Stream { char* str; size_t pos; size_t size; };

static int ReadStream(void* opaque, uint8* buf, int buf_size) {
  Stream* strm = reinterpret_cast<Stream*>(opaque);
  int read = strm->size-strm->pos;
  read = read < buf_size ? read : buf_size;
  memcpy(buf, strm->str+strm->pos, read);
  memset(buf+read, 0, buf_size-read);
  strm->pos += read;
  return read;
}

static int64_t SeekStream(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence) {
  Stream* strm = reinterpret_cast<Stream*>(opaque);
  if (whence == AVSEEK_SIZE) {
    return strm->size;
  } else if (whence == SEEK_END) {
    strm->pos = strm->size;
  } else if (whence == SEEK_SET) {
    strm->pos = 0;
  }
  strm->pos += offset;
  return strm->pos;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  string content;
  GetContents("test.mp4", &content);

  avcodec_register_all();

  uint8* buff = (uint8*)malloc(4096 + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
  Stream strm = { const_cast<char*>(content.data()), 0, content.size() };
  void* opaque = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&strm);

  AVFormatContext* fmtctx = avformat_alloc_context();
  AVIOContext* avctx = avio_alloc_context(buff, 4096, 0, opaque, &ReadStream, nullptr, &SeekStream);
  AVInputFormat* ifmt = av_find_input_format("mp4");
  AVDictionary* opts = nullptr;

  fmtctx->pb = avctx;
  avformat_open_input(&fmtctx, "", ifmt, &opts);
  avformat_find_stream_info(fmtctx, &opts);
}
```

But that always segfaults at find_stream_info.

I also tried pre-demuxing the video stream into raw h264 and just sending the stream packets (e.g.):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  string content;
  GetContents("test.h264", &content);
  uint8* data = reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(const_cast<char*>(content.c_str()));

  avcodec_register_all();

  AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
  AVCodecContext* ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

  ctx->width = 1080;
  ctx->height = 1920;
  avcodec_open2(ctx, codec, nullptr);

  AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();    
  AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();

  pkt->data = data;
  pkt->size = 4096;
  avcodec_send_packet(ctx, pkt);
  data += 4096;
}
```

But that just gives a nondescript "error while decoding MB # #, bytestream #". Note that I've removed the error checking from the allocs, etc. to simplify the code, but I am checking to make sure everything is allocated and instantiated correctly.

Any suggestions for where my misunderstanding or misuse of avcodec is?

Comment: I literally know nothing about libavcodec, but my intuition tells me that you should be passing in a `nullptr` as the second argument to `avformat_find_stream_info` rather than a pointer to a `nullptr`.

Comment: @AlessandroPower That was something I tried recently. I _think_ AVDictionary always starts as null and that is why it is passed as a pointer to a pointer then, anytime you set a value, it instantiates if necessary. I was thinking that perhaps open_input would set values that find_stream_info might need, so I stopped just giving it a nullptr and instead giving it an avdict. Neither approach has any effect though.

Comment: Based Why did you pass test.mp4 into `avformat_open_input`?

Comment: @AlessandroPower what do you mean? `test.mp4` as a string is wrapped in the custom I/O handler, which is then attached as the I/O handler for the format context. That format context is then opened with `avformat_open_input`

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I meant to ask whey *didn't* you pass test.mp4 as a filename to `avformat_open_input`?

Comment: @AlessandroPower because I'm trying to get in-memory decoding to work. The resources I've read on this indicate that if you manually set a custom I/O handler you should pass a dummy filename into open_input. I don't want open_input to have access to the file, just the bytes I've read into memory already.